# Rust equivalent of hmac digest in Python

Tags: rust, hmac

I'm trying to find the Rust equivalent of the function below in Python. I've looked into the [hmac](https://docs.rs/hmac/latest/hmac/) crate but it's not clear how to get the same digest.

```py
import base64
import hashlib
import hmac


def hmac_signature(key, msg):
    hmac_buffer = hmac.new(
        key=bytes(key, 'utf-8'),
        msg=bytes(msg, 'utf-8'),
        digestmod=hashlib.sha256
    )
    return base64.b64encode(hmac_buffer.digest()).decode('utf-8')
```

### Attempt

```rust
use base64;
use sha2::Sha256;
use hmac::{Hmac, Mac};
use ring::{digest};


fn main() {
    let key = "secret";
    let msg = "message";

    let signature = hmac_signature(key, msg);

    let expected = "i19IcCmVwVmMVz2x4hhmqbgl1KeU0WnXBgoDYFeWNgs=";

    assert_eq!(signature, expected);
}

fn hmac_signature(key: &str, msg: &str) -> String {
    type HmacSha256 = Hmac<Sha256>;
    
    let mut mac = HmacSha256::new_from_slice(key.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    mac.update(&msg.as_bytes());

    let code_bytes = mac.finalize().into_bytes();

    let hash = |v| digest::digest(&digest::SHA256, v);
    let digest = hash(&code_bytes);

    return base64::encode(&digest);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rust
use base64;
use sha2::Sha256;
use hmac::{Hmac, Mac};


fn main() {
    let key = "secret";
    let msg = "message";

    let signature = hmac_signature(key, msg);

    let expected = "i19IcCmVwVmMVz2x4hhmqbgl1KeU0WnXBgoDYFeWNgs=";

    assert_eq!(signature, expected);
}

fn hmac_signature(key: &str, msg: &str) -> String {
    type HmacSha256 = Hmac<Sha256>;
    
    let mut mac = HmacSha256::new_from_slice(key.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    mac.update(&msg.as_bytes());

    let code_bytes = mac.finalize().into_bytes();

    return base64::encode(&code_bytes.to_vec());
}
```